Amplifying a nanovolt sine wave signal from frequency range of 1 Hz to 30 kHz
I am having very duanting task of extracting faint sound wave that my piezo disc captures and creates output in nanavolts from 1 Hz to 30 kHz.
Piezo is not that great in sensitivity, and I cannot change this piezo with better version as it is locked, so I have to build a preamp that can amplify this faint nanovolt signals to respectable level. The sensor is also very high impedance at low frequency and its impedance is down to tens of ohms near 30 KHz. I am clueless how to get this thing working which I am trying to do so now since months, but in vain, so thought of asking the community for ideas. Even if I use lock in detection as some community post have suggested to similar questions, still my preamp has to be below 1nV at 1 Hz. I know one company who advertises that their amp has 1 nV/\$\sqrt{Hz}\$ @1Hz but I cannot tell its name because of legal reasons. Any ideas suggestions and tips would be very helpful.

use an LM394 transistor array as a massively parallel => low impedance and noise voltage amplifier for the front end.

In The sensor is also very impedance at low frequency there seems to be a missing word before "impedance". Can you [edit] the question to clarify how the sensor impedance behaves at low frequency. Also, can you include a link to the datasheet for the piezo disc?

There are sections in the book The "Art of Electronics" about this very subject. Alternatively just research low noise audio amplifiers. The design techniques used (such as paralleling the inpu transistors) can achieve noise levels in the audio range down to significantly less than 1nV/rootHz.

Sensor capacitive reactance at 1 Hz combined with amplifier input current noise may overwhelm your noise expectations. Consider a piezo sensor with a simple capacitance of 10 nF and an input noise current of 1 fA/rtHz. The noise voltage will be 16 nV/rtHz at 1 Hz due to noise current. You really need to include the complex impedance of the sensor over the frequency range of interest before anybody can give help.
